# In sharepoint 2013 web application(IIS) created in App server and web server ... how can i access it from WFE

Tags: 2013, app, server

By default sharepoint WEF and APP servers have the Microsoft sharepoint foundation web application service and workflow timer services. Web application and sitecollection created in APP server as well as WFE. how can I access the site from WFE. I am able to access the site using APP server name. It doesn't have host header or server name of WFE by default.

Thanks
cheraideva

Comment: What is the URL of the SharePoint Web Application you created - is it http://localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

this is expected behavior, when you create a web application it pick the app server( if you have more than 1 app server then the server hosting Central admin) and configure the Alternate Access Mapping with app server url. What you can do now

- When you are creating the Web application at that time make sure update the Public URL to wfe server name.

But you already created the Web application.

- You can go central admin > application management > Configure Alternate Access mapping. On this page update the settings, replace the APp server with WFE.